# Complicate SELECT in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Complicate SELECT

Hi , I am using SQL 2012 , and T-SQL

I have nexts all numerics columns in a big data table:
imp2012, imp2013, imp2014 ,  st2012, st2013, st2014 , coltot

Columns (imp2012, imp2013, imp2014) has values , but columns (st2012, st2013, st2014) has cero value and their final value depends on coltot and imp2012, imp2013, imp2014 columns, so, the real value for "st" columns are:

```
if coltot > imp2014
        st2014 = imp2014
        vartemp = coltot - imp2014
        if vartemp > imp2013
            st2013 = imp2013
            vartemp = vartemp - imp2013
            if vartemp > imp2012
                st2012 = imp2012
            else
                st2012= vartemp
        else
            st2013=vartemp
    else
        st2014 = coltot
```

I need to cosntruc a SELECT fills st2012,st2013,st2014 columns apply the algoritm above.

It is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! First of all, please read the [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). StackOverflow community is not a code generator engine. Please share us what did you tried, what was the problem with it, which part of the solution should us help.

Comment: IF is a statement that is used to control flow of a process. I think you need to look at the CASE expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select
Case When coltot > imp2014 
        Then imp2014
    Else coltot
End As st2014,
Case When (((coltot - imp2014) > imp2013) AND (coltot > imp2014))
        Then imp2013
    When coltot > imp2014
        Then coltot - imp2014
    Else Null
End As st2013,
Case (((coltot - imp2014 - imp2013) > imp2012) AND (coltot > imp2014 + imp2013))
        Then imp2012
    When (((coltot - imp2014) > imp2013) AND (coltot > imp2014))
        Then coltot - imp2014 - imp2013
    Else Null
End As st2012,
coltot, imp2014, imp2013, imp2012
```

The important thing to note about your initial logic is that SQL does not really support that way of thinking.  What your if statements do is essentially create a dynamic select statement. If the first condition fails then you will only be selecting st2014 if the second condition fails you will only select st2014 and st2013.

Queries should result in a predictable amount of columns. Without this you can end up with read errors in your business logic when trying to read the result set.